# Enumerating Chrome Extensions and Plugins from Preferences file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a C++ project that will read a Chrome Preferences file and enumerate Extensions and Plugins from it.

The main requirement is that only those extensions and plugins displayed in `chrome://extensions` and `chrome://plugins` should be used/displayed by my app.

1. Does anybody know which setting for an Extension determines if it is displayed under `chrome://extensions`? I can't find the logic behind...
2. Does anybody know the set of rules that will group the plugins as they show in `chrome://plugins`? Is it name, version or ... I can't find the logic behind as well

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer, but to my knowledge there is no setting to prevent an extension showing up from the `chrome://extensions` tab - everything installed will appear (you can hide the icons that show up in the toolbar, but everything will be visible in `chrome://extensions`. Therefore (again, according to what I've read and my somewhat limited experience), all installed extensions appear in `chrome://extensions` (this is primarily for security reasons).

Regarding the plugins, which particular grouping are you referring to? My groupings appear to happen when either there are multiple files in the same package (inclusive of Firefox plugins as well, oddly enough). See [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/jzagvx7wvgw) for a little more detail, and sorry if that wasn't as specific as you're looking for :)

Comment: Extensions:
If you install YouTube extension it will end up in the "New Tab->Apps" page and it is not showing in the "chrome://extentions". You can't disable it as well. What is the settings that determines this? Is it the "location": 1?  
  
Plugins:
For example, I have "Flash" and "Shockwave" groups.
Under Flash group I have 2 plugins name "Shockwave Flash"
Under Shockwave group I have 1 plugin name "Shockwave for Director"  
  
What is the rule to group the plugins? Why "Shockwave Flash" ends up in "Flash" group and not under "Shockwave" group? Very confusing.

Comment: @htome Regarding the YouTube app, that is actually a difference between Apps and Extensions. Apps (here is a basic writeup - http://www.ghacks.net/2011/01/18/the-difference-between-google-chrome-extensions-and-web-apps/). Therefore anything that is an app (i.e. that appears on that tab) is not an extension and will not appear in `chrome://extensions`. Agree on the plugins - my best guess is it has something to do with the overall plugin package, but I don't want to say anything that is certainly wrong as I don't have much experience in that area.